# I keep getting this error, my script does not contain a definition for the 'name' in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm trying to add a dash to my 3D Platformer, but I keep getting this error. I've made sure that the variable is consistent and that it's being defined. I'd be very thankful for any help as I've been attempting to fix it myself for hours. The definition should be on line 112. Sorry if this is really simple!

error CS1061: 'ThirdPersonMovement' does not contain a definition for 'moveDirection' and no accessible extension method 'moveDirection' accepting a first argument of type 'ThirdPersonMovement' could be found (the error I'm getting)

Here's a link to my script - https://gdl.space/sazibapotu.cs

Comment: Could you post the exact complete error message? Including the script and line which is throwing it?

Comment: And can you add  in your post the code/method contained around the line number 112 you mention.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting this error somewhere outside the script you shared. For example, you are trying to access `moveDirection` of your `ThirdPersonMovement` script in another script. If so, the error is clear: indeed your `ThirdPersonMovement` class doesn't declare the `moveDirection` field. All your `moveDirection` declarations are inside methods: `MovementStafe` and `LateUpdate`.

If you need to access `moveDirection` outside the `ThirdPersonMovement` class body, declare `moveDirection` as a field like you do for `jumpHeight`, for example.